# Performance of non-focused apps drops singificantly on Windows 11

Tags: performance, windows-11, cpu-throttling

When running two distinct GPU-heavy app on my Windows 11 (each occupying separate screen) the app not having the focus has recently started to drop significantly in performance.

I am basically testing my own network game, and performance for rendering a frame drops from 1-2ms to 500-550 ms (yes, it means little less than 2 FPS instead of 500-1000 FPS!). This behavior started to appear recently (Windows update maybe?), as I've successfully developed a network game before, without any problems.

The game engine is Unity, but I've already confirmed common checks (like "Running/Visible in background" checkbox). The Unity employee gave a hint that it might be a Windows thing, so I am asking here.

What can I do to verify and revert this Windows behavior?

Comment: Isn't this expected throttling behavior on the Windows side?  I remember playing games in windowed mode and whenever I would Alt-Tab out the window, the background window would still render frames but slower.  It is most likely controlled by the DWM process, I couldn't find any APIs related to this behavior though.

Edit: This would occur all the way back to Windows 7

Comment: @imsirovic I believe it started to happen only recently. Earlier on (in terms like a few months ago) I was able to work without that problem

Comment: What type of device are you using? Laptop or Desktop, and does it have 2 GPUs (Integrated and Dedicated).  Could be a chance that the renderer is dropping to the integrated GPU when in the background (I cannot confirm this).  Other than that I am very familiar with the platform and had this same exact thing happen to me on a regular basis, regarding any 3D application so I'm half expecting this to be the expected behavior.  Regarding Windows 11, you may wanna take a look at Virtualization Based Security (VBS) and see what happens when you disable that?

Comment: @harrymc Interesting solution, will bookmark this once I upgrade to a modern CPU.

Comment: @imsirovic It is Desktop PC - it has nVidia GPU (RTX series)

Comment: @harrymc Yup, that was it! `powercfg /powerthrottling` worked like a charm. Can you post it as the answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: I can't post an answer, since your question is a duplicate of the link I gave. I suggest to delete this question, or it will probably be closed by vote anyway.